# Can't add file upload capability to generated MVC3 page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to MCV and I'm learning MVC3.  I created a model and a controller and view was generated for me.  The generated code makes perfect sense to me.  I wanted to modify the generated view and controller so that I could upload a file when I "create" a new record.  There is a lot of good information out there about how to do this.  Specifically I tried this: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx

The problem is that even when I select a file (not large) and submit, there are no files in the request.  That is, Request.Files.Count is 0.

If I create the controller and and view from scratch, in the same project (no model), the example works just fine.  I just can't add that functionality to the generated page.  Basically, I'm trying get the Create action to also send the file.  For example, create a new product entry and send the picture with it.

Example Create view:

```
@model Product.Models.Find

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Find", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Find</legend>

        <input type="file" id="file" /> 


    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Example Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files[0] != null)
            {
                //Not getting here
            }

            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(find);
    }
```

This will create the record just fine but there are not files associated with the Request.

I've also tried a controller action like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //Not getting here
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I'm wondering if maybe you can't post a file at the same time as posting form fields?  If that is the case, what are some patterns for creating a new record and associating a picture (or other file) with it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a ViewModel which has properties to handle your image and Product deatils

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
 public string ImageURL { set;get;}
 public string Title { set;get;}
 public string Description { set;get;}
}
```

And in your HTTPGET Action method, return this ViewModel object to your strongly typed view

```
 public ActionResult Create()
 {
        ProductViewModel objVM = new ProductViewModel();
        return View(objVM);
 }
```

And in your View

```
@model ProductViewModel 
<h2>Add Product</h2>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title) <br/>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description ) <br/>
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload"  />
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ImageURL )
}
```

Now in your HttpPost action method, accept this ViewModel and File

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file, ProductViewModel objVM)
{
  if(file==null)
  {
     return View("Create",objVM);
  }
 else
 {
    //You can check ModeState.IsValid if you have to check any model validations and do further processing with the data here.
    //Now you have everything here in your parameters, you can access those and save
 }        
}
```

Comment: This is very close to what I already had but I updated my HttpPost from "Create(HttpPostedFileBase file)" to "Create(HttpPostedFileBase file, ProductViewModel objVM)" my product does come over in objVM but "file" is still null.  It sounds like I should be able to do this but file is always null.  I know the file isn't too big and I am setting enctype = "multipart/form-data".  Not sure why it is null.

Comment: @FeatureCreep : give `name="file"` to you file upload input.

Comment: Doh!  I missed that.  I was setting id an not name.  Yes, that was it.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a ViewModel for `Product` (maybe `ProductViewModel`) and add a `HttpPostedFileBase` field with the same name as the field of the form and use that instead of the `Product` in the action of the controller.

A ViewModel is nothing but a model used for specific views. Most of the times, with extra data to generate the view or to decompose and form the model on the controller action.

```
public ProductViewModel
{
    public string Cod { get; set; }
    // All needed fields goes here

    public HttpPostedFileBase File{ get; set; }

    /// Empty constructor and so on ...
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought I was doing with my other example at the bottom of my post.  In that case, "file" is null.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point. Forget that. See the Shyju's answer.